# Proving equation of sets.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Consider

$$(A \cup B) - C = (A - C) \cup (B - C)$$

I have no idea how to prove this set.

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Work on both inclusions  $\subseteq$ and $\supseteq$.

For a start, let $x \in (A \cup B) - C$ then $x \in (A \cup B)$ and $x \notin C$. That tells us that $x \in A$ and $x \notin C$ or $x \in B$ and $x \notin C$.

You take it from here.

Comment: So to finish it I basically just do the same to the other side and then explain that they are equal I got that far but I don't know how to explain the proof? It seems so simple so I can't figure out how to show it!

Comment: By definition if $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$ you have that $A=B$. It's important that you give it a try, show that every element in $(A-C) \cup (B- C)$ is in $(A \cup B) - C$ .

Answer (score 1):

here $C^c$ will be complement of $C$.
$$(A \cup B) - C =(A \cup B) \cap C^c= (A \cap C^c) \cup (B \cap C^c)=(A - C) \cup (B - C)$$

Comment: I used *PROPOSITION 9* (part 9 of it), and *Distributive law*: [$here$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets)